# Convert and compare grep result with integer

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am trying to compare a result obtained from grep with a integer in unix. But I cannot compare that string to integer. My code goes like this..

```
set e_pat = `zgrep "count" $file | cut -d'=' -f 2`
if [$e_pat -gt 10000]
  then
      echo "Greater"
else
      echo "lesser"
fi
```

This code gives error

> if: Expression Syntax.

How to convert and compare the grep command result with integer?

Comment: try `if [ $e_pat -gt 10000 ]` spaces are missing

Answer (score 1):

In bash, `set` is not used to assign values to variables. Instead, use `=` directly, but *without spaces around the assignment operator*:

```
e_pat=`zgrep count "$file" | cut -d= -f2`
```

It's better to use `$()` instead of the backticks, as you can nest it without needing to backslash.

```
e_pat=$(zgrep count "$file" | cut -d= -f2)
```

Also, quote the variable in comparison, and separate the command `[` from it by whitespace; the same applies to the closing `]`.

```
if [ "$e_pat" -gt 10000 ]
```

Comment: Backticks are really deprecated since like decades